# How to make PhpStorm save most current code?

Tags: save, phpstorm

I recently started using PhpStorm and love it so far, but for whatever reason it often won't automatically save the most current code.  For example, I'll have:

```
#aDiv {
    color: #333;
}
```

but when I go to view the page for testing purposes, it'll show up as:

```
#aDiv {
    color: #33
}
```

and completely leave off the last 3 and semicolomn.  Is there any way to force a save or fix this issue?

I guess I should note that this only seems to happen when I'm working with scss or sass.  Maybe it's an issue with running the Ruby to create the newest css?

EDIT: I added a screenshot of my filewatcher: http://i.imgur.com/dplS9TZ.png

Comment: Do you have File Watcher setup to compile your SASS/SCSS ? If so -- what are the settings?

Comment: Is the server you're testing on running any kind of CDN like CloudFlare?

Comment: @LazyOne: Here's a screenshot of my filewatcher settings: http://i.imgur.com/dplS9TZ.png

Comment: @Noah: Not at the moment.  Just the default development environment since I've just set everything up.

Comment: You can turn off `Immediate file synchronization` option so that file save will occur only on actual file save operation and not within 1 sec after typing anything. See if that will help here (it should).

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much.  Hopefully this fixes it.